# Africaans language support by android

Tags: android

I would like to create an android application that support '**Africaans**' language, it is the regional language of **South Africa**. My question is:

Does Africaans language is supported by Android OS? 
How do we use Locale class for this [like new Locale("en") use for English]?
What will be the values folder name [like values-en for English].
If there are any other approach for the same post must suggest.

If anyone has any idea regarding the question post, will be very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, Android does not have an Africaans locale yet even in ICS. Your other questions would be answered here in the official Localization  documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 0):

It's called Afrikaans.

It uses the Latin script, so you won't have any problems.

Language code is af or afr depending upon the ISO.

http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php